# Conditional useEffect not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am using **useEffect** as below in a function component. According to the [document](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect), React will perform useEffect only when one of the dependencies changed, but here in my code the console is still getting called even the dependency is a constant value. Does it still run on every render?

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('*** hi, I am still getting called ****');
}, [20]);
```

Comment: You're passing in an inline value, so that will be new on every render. That dependency isn't a variable that's stored anywhere in memory, it's created transiently as the render executes, then it's lost. Even though it's just a number, since it's not stored anywhere it's considered a "new instance" of that number on the next render. You can't pass in inline values in the dependency array, since those aren't preserved between renders

Comment: This `useEffect` will only print your message once on first render. It won't run on every subsequent re-render.

Comment: @Jayce444 Thanks! so if I set dependency  as a state in a store, and let's say that state never changes, then it won't cause it to perform the useEffect code?

Comment: @flyingbee yes correct, the standard use case for the dependency array for simple values like numbers/strings is that if the actual value itself changes then it triggers the effect. This is different for values stored by reference, such as functions or arrays. Basically React does a shallow comparison of the values to see if they've changed, and inline values *always* change, cos they aren't stored in memory between renders. Your example isn't how you'd do it in the real world, if that makes sense

Comment: This gets into a bit of computer science-y stuff and the inner working of Javascript, relating to how values are stored in a computer's memory, but yes if you used the dependency array in a traditional sense and passed in some value that was stored somewhere else in a persistent store, then it would work properly